# Protocol, implementation, and caller, in three namespaces

Tags: clojure

I've got three files/ns called `world.clj`, `node.clj`, and `protocols.clj`. The `Node` record implements a protocol called `movable`. Then I'd like to call that from `world.clj` (which maintains the state of nodes etc), but I'm unable to figure out how. What do I need to `:require` where?

protocols.clj:

```
(ns mesh.protocols)

(defprotocol movable
  (move [this pos])
```

node.clj:

```
(ns mesh.node
  (:require [mesh.protocols :refer [movable]]))  

(defrecord Node [...]
  movable
  (move [this pos] ...))
```

world.clj:

```
(ns mesh.world
  (:require ???))

(defn update-world [world]
  ...
  (move node new-pos))
```

What do I need to require in `world.clj` to be able to call the implementation of `move` in `Node`? I get various exceptions such as below depending on what I try.

- `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: move in this context, compiling:(mesh/world.clj:13:29)`
- `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: move does
  not exist, compiling:(mesh/world.clj:1:1)`

Is it possible to resolve this with the correct `:require` or do I need to move stuff around? And how would you recommend that I organize the stuff instead in that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`defprotocol` (among other things) defines functions in the enclosing namespace. The client just calls these 'polymorphic' functions just like they would call any regular function.

```
(ns mesh.world
  (:require [mesh.protocols :as meshp]))

(defn update-world [world]
  ...
  (meshp/move node new-pos))
```